# bitwise concatenate and or difference

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have trouble understanding the difference between bitwise concatenate and or.
For example, I have to bianry values which is 1111 and 0000.
If I do 1111 | 0000, will I get 1111 or 11110000?
And if I get 11110000 as the result, when should I use | as or operation?

Comment: `1111 | 0000` will bitwise-or your two numbers, i.e. four times (`1 or 0`), giving `1111`. To concat them, you could do `(1111 << 4) | 0000`, where `4` is the length of your zero-chain. (This is the same as just shifting `1111 << 4`)

Comment: There is no bitwise concatenate, because `0000` is the same thing as `0`, there is no "count" for the number of zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1111 | 0000` is `1111`. There is no bitwise concatenate operator.  You can use left shift `<<` to move bits to the left `1111 << 4` is  `11110000`.